# How to find smallest subarray that contains all elements 1 to k at least once for a given k in linear time

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sub-array

Suppose the array is {2 4 2 1 5 3 5 3} and k=3.
subarray {2 1 5 3} contains 1 2 3.

I want to know if there is a linear time algorithm to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is:

```
begin = -1
end = -1
best = 0
new = 1
finalbegin = -1
finalend = -1
for i = 1 to n
    if (new and input[i] >= 1 and input <= k)
        begin = i
        new = 0
    end if
    if (new and (input[i] <= 1 or input[i] >= k) or (i = n))
        if (input[i] <= 1 or input[i] >= k)
            end = i - 1
        else
            end = i
        end if
        new = 1
        if (end - begin >= best)
            finalbegin = begin
            finalend = end
            best = end - begin + 1
        end if
    end if
end for
```

Whenever you find a new interval, you check whether it is better than the best found already. If so, you handle it as the new best. If begin and end is negative, then empty set is the solution. Otherwise the best found is the solution